# How to fix amqp error in Window OS running PHP 7.2.2?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

I downloaded php_amqp-1.9.4-7.2-nts-vc15-x64 and php_amqp-1.9.4-7.2-ts-vc15-x64 and tried both ,but on running

```
 php.exe -m
```

I get following error.

Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_amqp.dll' (tried:          C:\xampp\php\ext\php_amqp.dll (%1 is not a valid Win32 application.
), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_amqp.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.
)) in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I posted an answer here
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967199/install-amqp-in-windows-10-php-7-3/55907120#55907120](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54967199/install-amqp-in-windows-10-php-7-3/55907120#55907120) , which might help

Answer (score 1):

You can figure out your system specs with [phpinfo()](https://php.net/phpinfo).

- Thread safety and VC runtimes are shown at e.g. **PHP Extension Build**:

  [image: PHP Extension Build]
- Processor architecture is shown at **Architecture**:

  [image: Architecture]