# Install AMQP in windows 10 & PHP 7.3

Tags: php, windows, rabbitmq, amqp

i want to install AMQP in windows 10 with PHP 7.3 for use in symfony 4. windows not use any apache/iis/nginx and run directly by symfony.

everything ok!
until, i decide to use rabbitmq in project and need amqp for it.

So,
1. download [AMQP 1.9.4](https://pecl.php.net/package-info.php?package=amqp&version=1.9.4) (php 7.3 compatible)
2. copy php_amqp.dll to c:\php
3. copy rabbitmq.4.dll (AMQP 1.9.4 compatible)  to c:\windows\system32
4. add extension=php_amqp.dll > php.ini
5. php.ini extension_dir = "ext"

but i get this error:

```
PHP Warning:
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_amqp.dll'
(tried: ext\php_amqp.dll (The specified module could not be found.),
ext\php_php_amqp.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

i try these instruction:
1. change php.ini extension_dir to "C:\php\ext\"
2. install openssl 1.1
3. copy libeay32.dll,ssleay32.dll into "c:\windows\system32"
4. restart, restart, restart, ...

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Try:

- copying php_amqp.dll and php_amqp.pdb into \php\ext\
- copying rabbitmq.4.dll and rabbitmq.4.pdb into \php\

It didn't work for me with PHP 7.2.13RC1, but it works with PHP 7.2.17

I'm using Windows 10, x64, PHP non thread safe

Comment: That was the missing part for me: "copying rabbitmq.4.dll and rabbitmq.4.pdb into \php\"

Answer (score 2):

1) generate phpinfo file, check 
 - Architecture     ie: x86 
 - PHP Extension Build  ie: API20170718,TS,VC15 
 - Thread Safety    ie: enabled

2) go to https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp find version of library acording to your PHP ver, and thread safe or not thread safe

like here: https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp/1.9.4/windows

3) unzip/tar package
copy php_amqp.dll into ext dir in php dir (ie: c:/xammp/php/ext)

4) edit php.ini add "extension=php_amqp.dll"

copy rabbitmq.4.dll and rabbitmq.4.pdb into ie: c:/xammp/php

5) install Win32OpenSSL (save dlls in windows/system dir)

https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html

Comment: I am on windows 10, I skipped the step 5 and it works fine! thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Be shure you download compatible version **php** and **amqp** libriary (thread-save or no9t-thread-safe, x86 or x64).

For example:

- php 7.3.8 **ts** x64 link https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/php-7.3.8-Win32-VC15-x64.zip
- amqp 1.9.4 **ts** x64 for 7.3 link https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/amqp/1.9.4/php_amqp-1.9.4-7.3-ts-vc15-x64.zip

> links to all versions for windows:
>
> AMQP
>   https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp/1.9.4/windows
>
> PHP https://windows.php.net/download/

2. You need to register dll `regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\rabbitmq.4.dll`
   (or copy rabbitmq.4.dll to `c:\php\` dir)

and move php_amqp.dll to extension dir `move c:\php\php_amqp.dll c:\php\ext\`

Comment: After running, `regsvr32 c:\windows\system32\rabbitmq.4.dll` i get the following error.
I made sure to use right dlls for my php version and thread safety.


The module "c:\windows\system32\rabbitmq.4.dll" was loaded but the entry point DllRegisterServer was not found 

Make sure that "c:\windows\system32\rabbitmq.4.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem to install amqp with XAMPP(if that is a case)
Make sure you downloaded Thread-safe version for amqp
Rest of configuration is showed above

1. Add php_amqp.dll in **xampp/php/ext**
2. Add rabbit.dll **windows/system32**
3. in php.ini add extension=php_amqp.dll

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

copy rabbitmq.4.dll to php/ directory. That saved my life with php 8.1.4. First moved it to php/ext and doesn't work